# Center background image from sprite

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have menu as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Very very short Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Last Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to use sprite image as background in CSS. I would like the image to be centered in different width menu items. Currently, for the first item correct CSS is:

```
background: url(images/sprite.png) no-repeat -20px -10px;
```

For the second:

```
background: url(images/sprite.png) no-repeat -24px -10px;
```

For the third:

```
background: url(images/sprite.png) no-repeat -32px -10px;
```

And so on. I don't know the exact width of each element, and it can change at any moment.

I have access to HTML structure, so I can add some tags if it is needed.
Is it possible to center background image in that case?

Comment: nop, unless you use a pseudo element of the right size to clip the portion of your sprite, then center this pseudo-element

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle demo? It's impossible to help without seeing some of the details, e.g., what sprite are you using? How is it laid out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/cG5hr/).

Basically, you create a pseudoelement, use `position: absolute` and `left:50%` to center it.

```
li a { position: relative;} /* makes the (position:absolute) below work */
li a:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%; /* centers the left edge of the sprite */
    margin-left: -8.5px; /* this centers the actual sprite--this is half the sprite-window width. if you don't do this, the left edge will be centered instead of the center of the sprite.  */
    width: 15px; /* set window to see sprite through */
    height: 18px; /* set window to see sprite through */
    background: url(https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo129.png) no-repeat -15px -327px; /*  set up the sprite. Obviously change this fto make each one different. */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your background image is a vertically aligned sprite sheet, you can horizontally center each sprite like this:

```
li a {
    background-image: url(images/sprite.png); 
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: 50% [y position of sprite];
}
```

If your background image is a horizontally aligned sprite sheet, you can vertically center each sprite like this:

```
li a {
    background-image: url(images/sprite.png); 
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: [x position of sprite] 50%;
}
```

If your sprite sheet is compact, or you are not trying to center your background image in one of the aforementioned scenarios, these solutions do not apply.